Prophecies in Devarim 29 & 30 not fulfilled?
In Devarim 29:22 we see that G-d says that He will punish us by making our land “beyond sowing and producing”, but we see that before 1948, there was agriculture.
In Devarim 30, G-d says that if we return to Him and follow his commands, THEN He will return us to Israel etc. We see that in reality a majority of us (half of Jews worldwide) returned to Israel while most Jews are still not following the Torah at all, it’s safe to say that the level of faith is lower than when the Second Temple was destroyed, even more so when the biggest part of alyah was done in the beginning of the state of Israel. It seems that the prophecies do not match what happened in reality.
How to interpret this?

When I was in Israel in the 1990s a tour guide told us that Romans not only cut and burned most of the natural forests, but also plowed many aread and poured salt into the ground to prevent anything from growing there. I did not see any sources mentioning salting, but I did not investigate seriously. For sure, ashes would prevent anything from growing and then one needs to wait many years till it all gets washed off.


The Talmud says, that since God can be merciful and change his mind, negative prophecies don't have to be fulfilled. 2. As with the Messia, the sages didn't put any time limit on their fulfillment, as it says "I will await patiently". 3. I think that "כִּי־בָרֵךְ אֲבָרֶכְךָ וְהַרְבָּה אַרְבֶּה אֶת־זַרְעֲךָ כְּכוֹכְבֵי הַשָּׁמַיִם וְכַחוֹל אֲשֶׁר עַל־שְׂפַת הַיָּם וְיִרַשׁ זַרְעֲךָ אֵת שַׁעַר אֹיְבָיו׃" is far more problematic.


https://www.truetorahjews.org/_site/qanda/redemption

The Chazon Ish famously said: “Bring me a Gemora Kesubos.” They brought a Gemora Kesubos and he showed on page 111a the Three Oaths and their punishment. Then, holding his finger on the place, he said to the man, “Es shteit az men vet azoy ton vet azoy kumen, men hot azoy geton un es iz azoy gekumen, un ir zogt az es iz aschalta degeulah!” (It says that if we do this, this will happen. They did it, and it happened. And you say it’s the beginning of the redemption!) (Mishkenos Haro’im, p. 1195). That the State is now a fact, does not mean it is allowed according to Halacha.
